# Minimum/Maximum of a quadratic function of two variables subject to a quadratic constraint

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let $r = [x, y]^T $, define the quadratic function

$f(r) = r^T A r + b^T r + c $

I want to find the minimum/maximum of $f(r)$ subject to the quadratic constraint

$C(r) = r^T D r + e^T r + f = 0 $

where $A, D$ are symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices, $b, e$ are $2 \times 1$ vectors, $c, f$ are scalars.  It is further assumed that $D$ is positive definite.

How is this achievable ? What are the steps to finding the points $(x,y)$ that minimize/maximize $f(r)$ ?

For example, find the minimizing/maximizing points $(x,y)$ of the function

$f(x,y) = x^2 + 2 xy + 3 y^2 + 2x - y + 5 $

Subject to

$C(x,y) = 3 x^2 + 2 y^2 + xy + 2 x + 5 y - 10 = 0 $

Also, how would you tackle the general case where the number of variables is $n \ge 3 $?

This is an exercise in constrained optimization.

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: I this what I have tried, but I want to develop the answer to this question to be as general as possible and applicable to all quadratic functions with quadratic constraints as specified in the problem statement.  If you have a complete answer to my question, I would greatly appreciate you sharing it.

Comment: Since $D$ is PD, you may simplify the constraint to something like $z^\mathsf{T} z = 1$?

Comment: The SDP relaxation is probably the simplest and the most standard way to solve such problems.

Comment: Please let me know if  my answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the most general case of optimization problems that involve quadratic objective function $f$, not necessarily convex, with quadratic constraints, the problem can be written as:
\begin{align*}
& \text{minimize} \ f(\pmb{x}) = \pmb{x}^T A_{0} \pmb{x} + 2 \pmb{b}_{0}^T \pmb{x} + c_{0} \\
& \text{subject to: } \tag{P}\\
& \qquad \pmb{x}^T A_{i} \pmb{x} + 2 \pmb{b}_{i}^T \pmb{x} \leq c_{i} \quad \forall i = 1, \dots, m
\end{align*}
with variable $\pmb{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and given problem parameters: symmetric matrices $A_{i} \in S^{n}$, vectors
$\pmb{b}_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $c_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$. The problem (P) is a general case of the so-called *Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Programming (QCQP)*.

To find a solution, first note that the objective function $f$ can always be shifted by a constant without changing solution to the optimization problem. So assume $c_{0} = 0$. Furthermore, the problem can be homogenized by adding an auxiliary variable $x_{n+1}$ to get an equivalent problem:
\begin{align*}
& \text{minimize} \ \pmb{x}^T A_{0} \pmb{x} + 2 x_{n+1} \pmb{b}_{0}^T \pmb{x} \\
& \text{subject to: } \tag{HP}\\
& \qquad \pmb{x}^T A_{i} \pmb{x} + 2 \pmb{b}_{i}^T \pmb{x} \leq c_{i} \quad \forall i = 1, \dots,m \\
& \qquad x_{n+1}^{2} = 1
\end{align*}

This problem is in general NP-hard. One way to find an approximate solution in polynomial time is by using Semidefinite Programming (SDP). The SDP relaxation can be written as:
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dotp}{{ \bullet }}
& \text{minimize} \ \begin{pmatrix}
A_0 & \pmb{b_0} \\
\pmb{b_0}^T & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \dotp X \\
& \text{subject to: } \tag{SDP}\\
& \qquad \begin{pmatrix}
A_i & \pmb{b_i} \\
\pmb{b_i}^T & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \dotp X \leq c_{i} \quad \forall i = 1, \dots, m \\[.5em]
& \qquad \begin{pmatrix}
\pmb{0} & \pmb{0} \\
\pmb{0} & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \dotp X = 1 \\[.5em]
& \qquad \, X \succeq 0
\end{align*}
where $X \in S^{n+1}$. Note that this problem is no longer quadratic but linear in $X$. This makes it computationally tractable.

To solve the nonlinear programs with a single equality constraint $g(\pmb{x}) = c_{1}$, as you specified in the problem statement:

- When objective function is convex ($A_{0}  \succeq 0$), the equality constraint can be replaced by a single inequality constraint $g(\pmb{x}) \leq c_{1}$. In **[2]** (*Appendix B.1: Single constraint quadratic optimization*) is described how the SDP relaxation produces the optimal value in this special case with a single constraint even when objective and constraint are both non-convex.
- In case when objective is not convex, the equality has to be replaced by two quadratic inequalities. But also in this specific case, they show in **[3]** that the corresponding SDP relaxation admits no gap with the true optimal value.

For the example that you provided, the objective function is convex ($A_{0}  \succeq 0$), and thus the equality constraint can be replaced by a single inequality constraint $g(\pmb{x}) \leq c_{1}$. Plugging in the values, we get:
\begin{align*}
A_{0} &= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 3
\end{pmatrix},
\quad \pmb{b_{0}} = (1, -1/2)^{T}, \\[.5em]
A_{1} &= \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 2
\end{pmatrix},
\quad \pmb{b_{1}} = (1, 5/2)^{T},
\quad  c_{1} = 10
\end{align*}

A step-by-step solution how to solve this SDP relaxation in CVXPY, where operator `@` denotes matrix-matrix multiplication and operator `>>` denotes matrix inequality:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

A = np.array([[3, 1/2, 1], [1/2, 2, 5/2], [1, 5/2, 0]])
B = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
C = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 3, -1/2], [1, -1/2, 0]])
X = cp.Variable((3,3), symmetric=True)
constraints = [cp.trace(A @ X) <= 10]
constraints += [cp.trace(B @ X) == 1]
constraints += [X >> 0]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.trace(C @ X)), constraints)
prob.solve()
```

To construct the vector solution $\pmb{x}$, decompose solution $X = \pmb{x}^T \pmb{x}$ and transform back from homogeneous coordinates $\pmb{x} \rightarrow \pmb{x}/x_{n+1}$:

```
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm

x = sqrtm(X.value).real
x = x[0][:2]/x[0][2]
x
```

We get `array([-1.75002478,  0.74990864])` which is very close to the exact solution $\pmb{x^*} = (-7/4, 3/4)^T$. Similarly, to find the maximizer, use `cp.Maximize()` instead of `cp.Minimize()`. Both solutions are shown in the Figure **[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X344i.png)** below:

[image: Example]

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X344i.png)**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X344i.png

**[2]**: S. Boyd and L. Vandenberghe. Convex Optimization. Cambridge university press, 2004. [https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)

**[3]**: Ye, Y., Zhang, S.: New results on quadratic minimization. SIAM Journal on Optimization 14(1), 245–267 (2003)
https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.23.329&rep=rep1&type=pdf